# event.preventDefault() working in Chrome, but not in Firefox / IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, preventdefault

I know there are already a lot of questions on this subject, but I've read a lot of them and still couldn't get my script to work ...

I have a very basic slideshow which can be seen here : www.screations.net/wm (there are 3 slideshows, I have the same problem on all 3 of them)

Here is the code i use for the navigation :

```
<a href="#"><img src="images/arrow_right.png" class="nextSlide" onclick="nextSlide();"/></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/arrow_left.png" class="prevSlide" onclick="prevSlide();"/></a>
```

And the jQuery (simplified) :

```
function nextSlide()
{
    $('.slide').eq(0).fadeIn(fadeSpeed);
    event.preventDefault();
}

function prevSlide()
{
    $('.slide').eq(0).fadeOut(fadeSpeed);
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Now this works fine on Chrome, but on Firefox / IE, while the script still works, it reloads the page. How can I fix this please ? :/

Thank you

Comment: You can't expect `event.preventDefault()` to work if you don't pass the event into the function...

Comment: …and if you don't expect an `event` parameter to your functions.

Comment: If you are using jQuery, why don't you use it to attach event handlers properly (instead of inline attributes)?

Comment: The real mystery here is why that code is working in Chrome, it shouldn't. It probably has to do with you attaching the event handlers to `img` tags which have no defaults.  `event` isn't a global, it should be passed into the handler as a parameter. `function nextSlide(event) { /* now event actually exists! */ }`.  As others have mentioned using `onclick` is a bad practice, give an id to the `a` tag and use jQuery to attach the event: `<a id="next">`, `jQuery('#next').click(nextSlide);`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seeing at the function body, there buble up two obvious problems

```
function nextSlide(){
 $('.slide').eq(0).fadeIn(fadeSpeed);
 event.preventDefault();
}
```

You didn't pass `event`, therefore when invoking this function, JS assumes that `event` comes from global scope. Second, you'd usually want to prevent default action before starting doing anything, like this:

```
function nextSlide(event) {
 event.preventDefault(); // <- That should come first
 $('.slide').eq(0).fadeIn(fadeSpeed);
}
```

And lastly, it doesn't make too much sense to use inline JavaScript when you have already included jquery.

So, I'd rewrite your thing as:

```
$("img.nextSlide").click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $('.slide').eq(0).fadeIn(fadeSpeed);

});


$("img.prevSlide").click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $('.slide').eq(0).fadeOut(fadeSpeed);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't expect the event to be prevented if you don't pass it into the function.

Change your links as follows:

```
onclick="nextSlide(event);"
```

Then, change your function as follows:

```
function nextSlide(event){ // <-- Accept the event parameter here...
    // Move this first in the function....
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.slide').eq(0).fadeIn(fadeSpeed);
}
```

Comment: @Bergi - good catch.  I was confusing inline script with other applications.

Comment: Hardly. Only the `event` identifier should be available for the event object in inline attribute handler code. You might use `function nextSlide(e) { e.preventDefault(); … }` of course.

Answer (score 0):

You run and you need to pass the event into the function.

You typically run event.preventDefault() before you do other stuff, but it's not 100% necessary.

```
$(function(){
    $("img.nextSlide").on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.slide').eq(0).fadeIn(fadeSpeed);
    })

    $("img.prevSlide").on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.slide').eq(0).fadeOut(fadeSpeed);   
    })
})
```

Comment: No. `event.preventDefault` just needs to be called within one of the handlers.

Comment: @Bergi Ok you are right, it's not 100% necessary. But you do typically  do it for readability. Edited my answer.

Comment: He's using classes, not ids. A selector should be `img.slideNext` not `#slideNext`